# how to invoke java file programatically

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am novice to Java coding.

I have a framework where i configure my tests in a excel test data where it contains the java test(class name) and corresponding test data with execute flag.

I will have a driver script, which check execute flag and if it is Yes, that java test has be run.

Can someone tell me how to invoke/execute that java test/class?

Thanks,
Uday

Comment: will you be writing the driver script in java?

Comment: Yes, my driver script is also in Java.

Comment: Can someone throw light on this?

Answer (score 0):

See examples [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/ctorInstance.html)
1. If you are using the default constructor (without arguments) it is easier

```
yourClass cInst = yourClass.newInstance();
```

2. Otherwise you have to find a constructor that matches your arguments

```
Constructor ctor = yourClass.class.getDeclaredConstructor([arg0].class,[arg1].class,...);
ctor.setAccessible(true);
yourClass cInst = (yourClass)ctor.newInstance([arg0],[arg1],...);
```

3. By the way to retrieve a class object from a String (Since you are reading from an excel file) use:

```
 Class<?> yourClass = Class.forName(yourClassName);
```

Comment: As i said i am novice, i am not sure how much i understand, but what i need is, there is a test called ABC.java in a java src folder, My driver script reads this into a variable name say strTestName="ABC.java", Now how to execute this java file? If i create an object like, ABC objClass =ABC.newInstance() will execute the java test?